# Pandas - Multiple data frame multiple column conditional check and assignment

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

How do I check if data in a column is equal to *any* data in another column in a different data frame?

Here is some df_out1 data:

```
'LN'      'E'   'DATE'

SMITH     H     '4-2-2000'
HARPER    A     '2-9-2018'
JONES     NaN   '1-1-2000'
```

Here is some ef_file_in data:

```
'LN'     'E'   

PERRY     F
JONES     H
SMITH     B
```

Here's what I wrote:

```
df_out1.loc[df_out1['E'].isnull() & df_out1['LN'] == ef_file_in['LN'], 'LN'] = 
ef_file_in['E']
```

This is the result I was looking for:
df_out1 data:

```
'LN'      'E'   'DATE'

SMITH     H     '4-2-2000'
HARPER    A     '2-9-2018'
JONES     H     '1-1-2000'
```

But, it looks like it's only checking if df_out1['LN'] == ef_file_in['LN'] on the same row, instead of checking df_out1['LN'] == *any* spot in ef_file_in['LN'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.isin()` method to locate those rows

```
df_out1.loc[df_out1['E'].isnull() & df_out1['LN'].isin(ef_file_in['LN'])]
```

Edit: after seeing your data, I think I get what you want

```
import pandas as pd
df_out1 = pd.DataFrame({'LN':['SMITH','JONES','HARPER'],
                     'E': ['H',np.nan,'F'],
                   'DATE':['4-2-2000', '2-9-2018', '1-1-2000']})

ef_file_in = pd.DataFrame({'LN':['PERRY','JONES','SMITH'],'E': ['F','H','B']})

# merge the two dataframes to get all in one
df_out1 = pd.merge(df_out1,ef_file_in,on='LN',how='left')

#       LN  E_x DATE    E_y
# 0 SMITH   H   4-2-2000    B
# 1 JONES   NaN 2-9-2018    H
# 2 HARPER  F   1-1-2000    NaN

# Now E has changed to E_x and you have a new column E_y form ef_file_in

# get a new column E = copy E_x except when null, then get E_y
df_out1['E'] = np.where(df_out1.E_x.isnull(),df_out1['E_y'],df_out1['E_x'])

# drop E_x and E_y, not useful now
df_out1.drop(columns=['E_x','E_y'],inplace=True)

# Notice that column E is not null anymore for LN=Jones
#   LN      DATE        E
# 0 SMITH   4-2-2000    B
# 1 JONES   2-9-2018    H
# 2 HARPER  1-1-2000    F
```

Comment: It's saying: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: please provide the first few lines of `df_out1` and `ef_file_in`in your initial post, otherwise it will be difficult to locate the issue

Comment: I just added sample data.

Comment: Thank you! Could you add the expected output as well please? What exactly do you want to do when you find a match?

Comment: I just added the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isin`:

```
df_out1.loc[(df_out1['E'].isnull()) & df_out1['LN'].isin(ef_file_in['LN']),  'LN'] = 
ef_file_in['E']
```

Comment: It's saying: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable