# append string to column based on values in two other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame

```
column1     column2     column3 
  nan        '3482'       nan
 '3322'      '3322'       nan
 '1282'       nan         nan
  nan         nan         nan
```

I want to append a string 'the string' to `column3` if either `column1` or `column2` is nonempty so that I get

```
column1     column2     column3 
  nan        '3482'    'the string'
 '3322'      '3322'    'the string'
 '1282'       nan      'the string'
  nan         nan         nan
```

How can I do this most efficiently (the actual data frame has quite many observations)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Multiple data frame multiple column conditional check and assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514212/pandas-multiple-data-frame-multiple-column-conditional-check-and-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where()` for this scenario and check on both conditions. For example:

```
df['column3'] = np.where(df['column1'].isna() & df['column2'].isna(),np.nan,'the string')
```

Essentially checkign if both are `nan`, the output is `np.nan`, otherwise `the string`.

This outputs:

```
   col1  col2        col3
0   NaN  3482  the string
1  3228  3322  the string
2  1282   NaN  the string
3   NaN   NaN         nan
```